Launch website upon unlock on Zebra MC2200 (Android-based handheld scanner)
I need an Android-based Zebra MC2200 handheld scanner to launch a website upon device unlock.
It's Android 11, but it's really minimalistic, Chrome isn't the normal Chrome.
I guess because these devices don't have a lot of RAM.
I tried Macrodroid and Tasker, but (although I use Macrodroid on my normal phone) it did not seem possible on this Android device (it didn't see the Chrome browser, I think because of how minimal this device is kinda strange).
Does someone know how to do it on these devices, or know of another app that I might try?

The main part of this question can be on-topic for this SE site, but software recommendations are off-topic.  You can post that on Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

okay sorry i'm a newbie here

There are at least 3 solutions that I could think of: 1) MacroDroid's built-in Open Website action, 2) ACTION_VIEW intent (my answer), 3) am (activity manager) shell command (probably needs root). However, since I don't have the device, I don't know the limitations, and thus a bit wary of posting multiple answers for choices, unless the question could be generalized without a specific device.

As for this specific device: is it possible to download any app or install any APK? What automation configuration have you tried that failed?

Assuming there is a web browser/app that captures ACTION_VIEW intent, it should be possible to use any automation apps that can fire an intent.
Tasker

Profile: Event - Display Unlocked
Task: System - Send Intent

Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
Data: https://example.com
Target: Activity



MacroDroid

Triggers: Device Events - Device Unlocked
Actions: Connectivity - Send Intent

Target: Activity
Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
Data: https://example.com



